# Remove ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION clearly from cordova app

Tags: android, cordova

Good day.

In my cordova app I don't use ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, and there is no any uses-permission strings about ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION in config.xml neither in AndroidManifest.xml, but when I try to upload APK into Google Play, it's failed and Google says that I use at least one feature that uses access to the location in background. I want to delete ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION clearly.
What I need to do?
I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
```

to AndroidManifest.xml. Is that enough?

Comment: Are you using any third party libraries that might have added this permission?

Comment: I think no, but I will check this now. Almost when I search ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION through project nothing founds.

Comment: @Dmitry Dagadin, did you find any solution?